# Trying to call object methods in array

Tags: php, forms, oop, object, input

Im learning php and i made this simple class for creating form.

```
class form {

private $pole= array();

function addText($name, $label){

    $pole[] = new input($name, 'text', $name, $label);
}

function create(){
    foreach ($this->pole as $polozka) {
        $polozka->addInput();
    }
}
}

class input{

private $name;
private $type;
private $id;
private $label;

/*
 * $name, $type, $id, $label
 */
function __construct($name, $type, $id, $label){
    $this->name=$name;
    $this->type=$type;
    $this->id=$id;
    $this->label=$label;
}

function addInput(){
    echo "<label for='".$this->name.": '>".$this->label."<input type='".$this->type."' name='".$this->name."' id='".$this->id."'/>";
}

}
```

And then Im calling it like this

```
<?php include "form.php";

$form = new form();
$form->addText('jmeno', 'Jméno');
$form->addText('prijmeni', 'Příjmení');
$form->create();
?>
```

but it does absolutely nothing. :( Dont you know whats wrong with it?

I think the problem may be with calling the object in array or saving them to array. Im used to do it like that from java. but yes, its a but different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function addText($name, $label){

    $this->pole[] = new input($name, 'text', $name, $label);
}
```

not

```
function addText($name, $label){

    $pole[] = new input($name, 'text', $name, $label);
}
```

You should probably also add a visibility of `public` to the methods in your classes... while they'll default to public anyway unless defined otherwise, an explicitly defined visibility does make it immediately obvious

Comment: Thank you very much guys!!

I was looking for the mistake nearly 20 minutes and I didnt see it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not referring to your class member:

```
function addText($name, $label){
    $pole[] = new input($name, 'text', $name, $label);
}
```

Should be:

```
function addText($name, $label){
    $this->pole[] = new input($name, 'text', $name, $label);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys!!

I was looking for the mistake nearly 20 minutes and I didnt see it.